# builtin [ , -bash: [: missing `]'

Tags: command-line, bash

while going through learn bash the hard way, I found that `[` and `test` are both commands and synonyms, and both are builtin.
As it is a builtin it should not give any error for  `builtin [` , but I am getting `` -bash: [: missing `]' ``, 
    Can someone explain me the behavior of builtin here. 
Thanks in advance.

```
anupam:Markdown$ which [
/usr/bin/[
anupam:Markdown$ echo $?
0
anupam:Markdown$ which test
/usr/bin/test
anupam:Markdown$ echo $?
0
anupam:Markdown$ builtin test
anupam:Markdown$ echo $?
1
anupam:Markdown$ builtin [
-bash: [: missing `]'
anupam:Markdown$ echo $?
2
anupam:Markdown$
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `[` version of the command requires `]` as the mandatory last parameter (so it must be [preceded by a space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134472/brackets-in-if-condition-why-am-i-getting-syntax-errors-without-whitespace)). It’s just a formal, syntactic thing to force users to close the bracketed “block”, so commands look this way:

```
if [ $1 -eq 2 ]; then
```

instead of

```
if [ $1 -eq 2; then
```

See `help [`:

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

### Notes

- The `test` version does not require nor accept the final `]`.
- You don’t need the `builtin` there. Builtins take priority over external commands, so just `[` would execute the builtin. The `builtin` command is more useful when you have a function or alias masking `[`.

Comment: Thanks @Melebius , so I checked for  ` builtin [ ] ` and it worked .

Comment: @jazzz you don't need the `builtin` there. Builtins take priority over external commands, so just `[` would execute the builtin. The `builtin` command is more useful when you have a function or alias masking `[`.

Comment: @muru Thank you for your edit and comment. I was not really aware of the `help` command (not available in Zsh which I use mostly). I’ve just changed my answer to wiki, feel free to include your note directly into the answer.

Comment: @Melebius :O You didn't need to do that! The answer was fine by itself, the edit was just supplementary information (and I could edit without CW anyway :P). Also, zsh user myself, so I added a function just for the times I need to quote `help`: `bh () (bash -c 'for i; do help "$i"; done' bash "$@")`

Comment: FYI, both spaces around the brackets are required too

Comment: For me, `test a = a ]` complains about having too many arguments. What makes you think `test` should accept a `]`?

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right. It seems to accept the empty expression (`test ]`) but an actual check does not work.

Comment: @Melebius: That's not an empty expression; that's an "is `]` a non-empty string?" query.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right again, thanks for pointing this out!